# Perl (... (*ACCEPT) ...)+ never matches

Tags: regex, perl

From the *perlre* man page:

> If the "(*ACCEPT)" is inside of capturing groups then the groups are
> marked as ended at the point at which the "(*ACCEPT)" was encountered.
> For instance:
>
> ```
>   'AB' =~ /(A (A|B(*ACCEPT)|C) D)(E)/x;
> ```
>
> will match, and $1 will be "AB" and $2 will be "B" ...

However if the second capture group has a quantifier, the pattern never matches:

```
'AB' =~ /(A (A|B(*ACCEPT)|C)+ D)(E)/x or die "No match";  #dies
                            ^
```

Why is this?  Replacing the **+** with ***** or {0,99} makes no difference.  *Any* quantifier on a capture group which encloses the `(*ACCEPT)` seems to prevent the *ACCEPT from working.  Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: It doesn't even match `ABDE`!

Comment: Looks like this is a Perl related issue since PCRE/PCRE2 [report no problems](https://regex101.com/r/pmarAy/1).

Comment: [Reported](https://github.com/Perl/perl5/issues/19484)

Comment: Fixed in upcoming 5.36

Answer (score 1):

The regex doesn't match because of a [bug fixed in Perl 5.36](https://github.com/Perl/perl5/issues/19484). The PCRE and PCRE2 libraries [aren't affected](https://regex101.com/r/pmarAy/1) by this bug; with the quantifier, the regex matches the "AB" in "ABCDE" and the entire string "ABDE" on regex101 website with both PCRE and PCRE2.